# Did Einstein introduce anything new to mathematics?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, notation

Newton introduced calculus, so I am wondering, did Einstein introduce anything important to mathematics?

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes or the close vote here. It is a relatively soft question, sure, but it admits an answer (possibly a good answer, if the right people chose to write one).

Comment: His [summation convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) shaved hours of writing from the composition process for many mathematicians, to say nothing of saving ink and paper (so also good for the environment!)

Comment: @WillieWong: Not only paper savings -- good notation is more importan than that. A more compact and to-the-point notations makes formulas easier to understand and grasp quickly, not to mention that it paved the way for _abstract index notation_, which I find at lot more compact, systematic and accessible than the traditional "mathematical" notation in differential geometry.

Comment: The summation convention is hated by many mathematicians.

Comment: The summation convention is loved by many mathematicians.

Comment: I'd say he really popularized the use of Tensor Calculus and Ricci Calculus. Prior to that, the only really significant use of either was during the time of Gauss around 1800. Especially since it is such an elegant calculus.

Comment: How about the Einstein tensor? I think he was the first to realise that $ \nabla^{\mu} (R_{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{2} g_{\mu \nu} R) = 0$ is an identity for the Ricci tensor.

Answer (score -4):

Ten of Einstein's equations were known as the Einstein Field Equations, published in 1915. One of these equations describes how stress-energy causes curvature of space-time. Of course, since physics is so close to math, Einstein contributed many mathematical laws.